# Gulp + source maps (multiple output files)

Tags: gulp, gulp-less

I just started playing with [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), and it's very fast and easy to use but it seems to have a critical flaw: what do you do when a task needs to output more than one type of file?

For example, [gulp-less](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less) says it doesn't even support the `sourceMapFilename` option. I don't want my source map embedded in my CSS file. Am I hooped? Should I just go back to using Grunt, or is there a way to deal with this?

Comment: [Gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if) might help with this. [example](https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-coffee/issues/16#issuecomment-35227635)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This task will take multiple files, do stuff to them, and output them along with source maps.

It will include the source code within the maps files by default, so you don't have to distribute the source code files too. This can be turned off by setting the `includeContent` option to `false`. See the [gulp-sourcemaps NPM page](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-sourcemaps) for more source map options.

**gulpfile.js:**

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var plugins = require("gulp-load-plugins")();

gulp.task("test-multiple", function() {
    return gulp.src("src/*.scss")
            .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(plugins.sass())
            .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer())
            .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write("./"))
            .pipe(gulp.dest("result"));
});
```

**package.json**

```
"gulp": "~3.8.6",
"gulp-load-plugins": "~0.5.3",
"gulp-sass": "~0.7.2",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "~0.0.8",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.1.0"
```

**The `src` directory:**

```
first.scss
second.scss
```

**The `result` directory after running the `test-multiple` task:**

```
first.css
first.css.map  // includes first.scss
second.css
second.css.map  // includes second.scss
```

Comment: Does this still work if there are partial .scss files imported via `@import` into a main .scss file? I would love it if the browser could link back to those partial files that were imported.

Answer (score -1):

Gulp supports multiple output files fine. Please read the docs.

Example:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/*js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This will read in a bunch of JS files, minify them and output them to the dist folder.

As for the gulp-less issue. You could comment on the relevant [ticket](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less/pull/5).

Comment: I did look through the docs. Where exactly does it say that? Also, your "relevant" ticket discusses *inline* source maps, which is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: Most of the examples through the docs output multiple files. I've added an example. As for the ticket, please read the thread and you'll see why there is no external Source Map support.

Comment: Your example looks like it only outputs one file to the dist folder. How's that multiple? In the thread, Contra says it's to avoid disk writes, but after I pointed out the problem with that, he seems to agree with me.

Comment: If you read the docs you'll realize `dist` is a folder: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath

Comment: This should be marked as correct. `gulp.src` uses globbing to match multiple files. Any file creation, manipulation, or deletion, will be output to the folder specified in `gulp.dest`. So when uglify creates a source map file, it also goes into `gulp.dest`.

Comment: @JamesKyle: You're saying you can configure `gulp-uglify` to write out both a `.map` and a `.js` file? And what if you want to pass just the `.js` through some more transforms?

Comment: @Mark if you're passing the .js files through more transforms, the source map file likely has to be updated too. You can also use [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-filter) if you don't want that. Still, this answer should be marked correct.

Comment: @JamesKyle It's my question; if I don't think this satisfies the requirements I laid out, then I'm not marking it was correct. It's mildly rude and ignores the intent of the question. I'm well aware that `.dest` can write out multiple files, but it doesn't address how we can deal with transforms that need to generate files of different types, which potentially need to be handled separately.

Answer (score -1):

In the [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath) it shows you how to have multiple output files:

```
gulp.src('./client/templates/*.jade')  
  .pipe(jade())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/templates'))
  .pipe(minify())`  
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/minified_templates'));
```

Comment: You're misreading the question. I'm talking about when a *single task* needs to output two or more separate files. I know I can call `.dest` as many times as I want; that doesn't help. This is to do with plugin architecture, not basic usage.

Comment: Gotcha :) Interested if it makes a difference in practise?

Comment: Source maps are very useful in practice. I'm sure there are many other scenarios where you would want to output two or more files of different types from a single task too; you can't split them into separate tasks otherwise each task has to reparse the input.